# improve select not in

Tags: mysql, performance

I hope this question has not been asked, I tried to search for similar questions but probably used the wrong keywords. Anyhow, I run into a situation where I have to search for customers who have never placed an order before, so the query runs like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
where customers_id NOT IN (SELECT customers_id FROM orders)
```

I read that it is not good to have nested `SELECT`s, so what is a better option?

Also, should I do `select *` or should I specify the fields, I also read somewhere that it is better to just `select *`?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: After seeing the answers I have a doubt about the EXISTS optimisation. Can you please time StilesCrisis and Joop Eggen's solutions and see which one runs faster? Thanks

Comment: mine: Showing rows 0 - 29 (5,390 total, Query took 0.0155 sec)

StilesCrisis: Showing rows 0 - 29 (5,390 total, Query took 0.0090 sec)

Joop Eggen: Showing rows 0 - 29 (5,390 total, Query took 0.0039 sec)

Note: I ran each only once, may need to run more times to get avg time right. Also, for Joop's one I used the SELECT *, wondering if things can improve if I do select with specific fields

Comment: Believe it or not, after multiple runs Joop's answer is still faster on my case.

Comment: All solutions are correct, so they should all return the same data. With the provided times (average of more data would be more accurate, though) it seems to be much more efficient Joop's solution. I thought the DBMS engine would recognize what it was intended regardless of the syntax used and optimize both queries.

Comment: Could you do an `EXPLAIN` on each of them and see how the plan differs? I'm quite curious now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.customers_id = orders.customers_id
WHERE orders.customers_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Dear StilesCrisis, thank you for the answer, very interesting solution, never thought of it

Answer (score 2):

The easy question: `SELECT *` is more costly than selecting some of the fields, It can be even dramatically. Less data, no table access if all fields in index. No marshalling from database field value to programming language variable.

Nested subqueries and joints have their right.

```
SELECT * FROM customers where customers_id NOT IN (SELECT customers_id FROM orders)
```

can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM orders o
                 WHERE o.customers_id = c.customers_id)
```

MySQL states that it can better optimize the EXISTS as recursively optimizing the select now has information on c.customers_id.

Though best would be the JOIN of @StilesCrisis, though I am in doubt it is correct. (I haven't drank my first cup of coffee for the day though.)

BTW. `EXISTS(SELECT *` does not really reserve space for all fields, and is okay.

Comment: Not sure why you doubt the `JOIN`. It's not real complicated.

Comment: There is now a **join** on customers_id but you want those customers where there exists _no_ such match. The null check does not influence that. Is it? NOOO You are right.

Comment: @StilesCrisis maybe a `SELECT DISTINCT`? Must say never used your pattern, though similar left joints.